# Visual Studio Code AWS Toolkit - How to connect using federated login -

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, federated, aws-toolkit

My company has provided me with a federated login to access the AWS Console.
I want to setup AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code; to work on lambdas.
Is it possible to use the federated login to setup and connect AWS Toolkit ?
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Here [Setting AWS credentials for the AWS Toolkit for JetBrains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/setup-credentials.html) you can find information for configuring SSO with [JetBrains IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

SSO Based authentication is not yet supported in [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html#adding-a-profile-to-the-aws-credentials-profile-file) as far as the documentation is concerned.

Comment: Now, it does support SSO for AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. 
Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/sso-credentials.html